# If attribute's value is one thing, echo another in shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements, echo, shortcode

Here's a shortcode of mine:

```
    function sc_link( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'page' => '',
            'style' => 'button',
            'window' => 'self',
            'label' => 'Missing Label Tag: label=""',
        ), $atts )
    ); 
    return '<a href="' . $page . '" class="' . $style. '" target="_' . $window . '">' . $label . '</a>';
}
add_shortcode( 'mylink', 'sc_link' );
```

What I want to be able to do is a conditional before the return: if $window = 'new' then echo 'blank'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this is what your trying to do what id suggest doing is leaving window blank and just doing an if statement on that

**How you want it**

```
    function sc_link( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'page' => '',
            'style' => 'button',
            'window' => 'self',
            'label' => 'Missing Label Tag: label=""',
        ), $atts )
    ); 

    if($window == "new"){
    $link = '<a href="' . $page . '" class="' . $style. '" target="_blank">' . $label . '</a>';
    }else{
    $link = '<a href="' . $page . '" class="' . $style. '" target="_self">' . $label . '</a>';    
    }

    return $link;
}
add_shortcode( 'mylink', 'sc_link' );
```

**How it should be**

```
    function sc_link( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'page' => '',
            'style' => 'button',
            'window' => '',
            'label' => 'Missing Label Tag: label=""',
        ), $atts )
    ); 

    if(!$window){
        $link = '<a href="' . $page . '" class="' . $style. '" target="_self">' . $label . '</a>';
    }else{
        $link = '<a href="' . $page . '" class="' . $style. '" target="' . $window . '">' . $label . '</a>';    
    }

    return $link;
}
add_shortcode( 'mylink', 'sc_link' );

The your shortcode will be link 

[shorcode page="" window="" label=""]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy short code conditional output example. I would recommend being sparing with this type of syntax because it can get lost in the fray.

```
echo ($window === 'new') ? $window : '';
```

This format is conditional ? what to do if true : what to do if false

Comment: Thanks for this. Trying to understand the syntax. How would I tell it to echo "blank" if value is "new"?

Comment: swap them. echo ($window === 'new') ? 'blank' : $window